# How do I make a .section in ELF format read only with GNU GAS?

Tags: assembly, elf, gnu-assembler

As I understand it these are the `.section` directives:

```
awxMSGT
```

The "old" directives if COFF format was used had "read only".

How do I make a .section in ELF format read only? No specifier at all?

Comment: Why not just try it out and decompile with `readelf -S` :-)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, empty flags makes it read only (any flags without an explicit w for writeable makes it read only) as you can verify for example using *objdump*.
So, `.section foo` or `.section bar, ""` both create a read-only section. You probably want to make it allocatable, though, so something like `.section baz, "a"`. This also  seems to automatically turn on `@progbits` (marked `LOAD` in objdump) to actually read the data from the file into memory. You can also specify that manually to be on the safe side. See the [GAS documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Section.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Taking a look at the GNU AS info, what I wrote below kind of answers it.  I'm pretty sure that just like in my linker script example, leaving the `w` out will note this section as being non-writeable.

---

Sorry if this is completely not what you were asking.  It sounded right so I took a stab at it!

So if you're talking about the linker then I think what your looking for is the `MEMORY` area of the linker script.

For example:

```
MEMORY
{
    flash (rx)  : org = 0x00000000 , len = 0x00080000
    sram  (rwx) : org = 0x40000000 , len = 0x00010000
}
```

The fact that I left the `w` out of my flash segment implies that it is read-only.  Then in the section specification later I use:

```
SECTIONS
{
    /* .text section (executable code) */
    .text :
    {
        blah blah blah
    } > flash
    _etext = . ;
    PROVIDE ( etext = . );

    /* .data section (read/write initialized variables) */
    .data : AT (_etext)
    {
        blah blah blah
    } > sram
}
```

I specify where each section is stored in memory in the section specification with the `> flash` or `> sram` to delineate if it is in read-only memory or not (and the `AT (_etext)` is to specify that it starts in read-only and is copied later).

I know you were specifically asking about the assembler, but this sounded like what I thought you were asking for.

Hope it helps!